# How to add elements to an array on a 'root' in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

In mongo I am constantly collecting data as I execute queries and then use group to keep track of the attributes I need to maintain. In my case a patient record that has lots of data and then when I get medications I then have to group every attribute I need to keep.

Below is an example.

```
{
        $group:{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "firstName":{$first:"$firstName"},
            "lastName":{$first:"$lastName"},
            "conditions":{$first:"$conditions"},
            "provider":{$first:"$provider"},
            "plans":{$first:"$plans"},
            "orgs":{$first:"$orgs"},
        }
    }
```

What I want I have been doing instead is:

```
  { 
      $group: { _id: "$Id", results: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } ,
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$results' } 
}
```

This seems excessive but the only way I could find to 'maintain' the complete patient information.

Is there a way to do this without having to do the replace?

The reason is I want to add medications to the patient record and while I can add it using the first method using :

```
{
        $group:{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "firstName":{$first:"$firstName"},
            "lastName":{$first:"$lastName"},
            "conditions":{$first:"$conditions"},
            "provider":{$first:"$provider"},
            "plans":{$first:"$plans"},
            "orgs":{$first:"$orgs"},
            "medications":{
                $push:"$medications"
            }
        }
    }
```

I cannot do this:

```
{ 
      $group: { _id: "$Id", 
          results: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
          "medications":{
                $push:"$medications"
           }
           ,
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$results' } 
}
```

But this is not allowed add 'attributes' when doing a results on a root.

Any suggestions on do this? Perhaps a way to have the $group just copy all attributes verses naming each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this :

```
   {
    $group: {
        _id: "$Id", "medications": {
            $push: "$medications"
        }, results: { $first: '$$ROOT' }
    } ,
    { $addFields: { 'results.medications': '$medications' } },
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$results' }
}
```

But the downside here would be medications will be an array for all the result documents irrespective of having multiple values/single/empty that's based on group operation(If you don't need that then you can have a cond at addFields to manipulate it).

Comment: Ok. Well I have some conditions on the query that will only return the right 'medications' .. as a result duplicates and such are removed. This seems to meet my need based on the results I see. Now I ran into the next issue which is now I copy the entire root including some 'temp' fields and I can't seem to find a way to remove fields during aggregation. only update. I can ask that as a separate question. Thank you again.

Comment: @Raphael : Use $project if there are few to be excluded or included, try to look into it if not then raise a new question. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html)

Comment: That is exactly what I did and it solved it. Thank you srinivasy.